# Insert a block directly into a template

Tags: template, blocks

I'm using the blacknwhite theme.  There instructions tell you to add a bunch of markup to the cms hompepage to set it up as per there demo.  I've dine this and it works but I'd rather put it in a template file as it will be easier to manage.

If I add the below to the cms page content I can call from a template

```
{{block type="core/template" template="monsoon/homepage.phtml"}}
```

But then how do I call the below from the template file:

```
{{block type="page/html_topmenu" block_id="catalog_topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php 
  echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_topmenu')->setBlockId('catalog_topnav')->setTemplate('page/html/topmenu.phtml')->toHtml();
?>
```